# Weblogic Subject propagation: where is the subject stored? 

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I need to understand how the subject is stored and propagated in Weblogic.

Once authenticated, where is the subject stored at the HTTP layer?
Internally, is it stored in `HTTPSession`?

Same way, where is it stored at the EJB layer?

I have an application where a lot of principals are updated in the subject at the HTTP  and EJB layers. In some corner cases, I'm getting a concurrent modification exception. Although the fix is simple, just to synchronize, I need to understand the internals of where the subject is stored at the HTTP and EJB layers.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to WebLogic implementation internals, which may even change from version to version so I would keep away from it.

You will find official information just for the public [Security APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/security/overview.html#wp1042212).